# How to use format function with dictionary in Python with integer keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

Given the `dict`:

```
dct = {1: 1, 2: 1}
```

How can I use this dict in a string format?  I tried:

```
print("{0[Key]},{1[Value]}  ".format(**dct))
```

Above code is giving me this error:

```
print("{0[Key]},{1[Value]}  ".format(**dct))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can't use integer keys as keywords in any sort of useful way. It seems you don't imediately get an exception about `**dct` using the `format` method since it's a builtin function written in C, but you would get a `TypeError` from the function call if `format` was a pure Python function.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use string formatting with a dict using integer keys, you can convert them to valid keywords before formatting via a dict comprehension:

**Code:**

```
dct = {1: 1, 2: 3}
print("{key_1},{key_2}".format(
    **{'key_%d' % k: v for k, v in dct.items()}))
```

**Results:**

```
1,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of desired output.

```
for k,v in dct.items()
    print("{0} is my key and {1} is my value".format(k,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for posting.
Allow me to elaborate my need. I am parsing a text file that contains the Wi-Fi channels. I am trying to get number of time(s) the channel occurs.

My text file (file_parse.txt) has:

```
Cell 29 - Address: B8:A3:86:61:C4:B3
               Protocol:IEEE 802.11a
               Channel:40
               Mode:Master
               ESSID:"dlink_media"
               IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101820003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
               IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
               IE: Unknown: DD810050F204104A0001101044000101103B00010310470010D5C
               Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                         36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
               Encryption key:off
               Quality=165/0  Signal level=-91 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
               Extra: Age: 2012
     Cell 30 - Address: 58:6D:8F:A1:67:05
               Protocol:IEEE 802.11a
               Channel:161
               Mode:Master
               ESSID:"CSR_5g"
               IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                   Group Cipher : CCMP
                   Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                   Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
               IE: Unknown: DD7F0050F204104A00011010440001021041000100103B0001031
               IE: Unknown: DD090010180200F0040000
               IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
               Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                         36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
               Encryption key:on
               Quality=163/0  Signal level=-93 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
               Extra: Age: 10259
     Cell 31 - Address: 8C:FD:F0:02:26:47
               Protocol:IEEE 802.11b
               Channel:161
               Mode:Master
               ESSID:"RC_2G"
               IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A5000027A500004254BC0062436600
               IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
               Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
               Encryption key:off
               Quality=165/0  Signal level=-91 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
               Extra: Age: 1806
```

with open(r"C:\Temp\file_parse.txt") as filename:

```
regex = re.compile("[C|c]hannel:[0-9]+")
count = 0

lst = []
new_lst =[]
for line in filename.readlines():
    if regex.search(line):
        count += 1

        lst.append(line)
        new_lst = [(lst[i].split(":"))for i in range(len(lst))]
        integer_lst = [int(new_lst[firstElement][1]) for firstElement in range(len(new_lst))]

def channel_count(lst):
    dct = {}
    for num in lst:
        dct[num] = lst.count(num)
        print('There are/is {1} channel {0} '.format(num, dct[num]))
```

channel_count(integer_lst)

Excepted Output:

There are/is 2 channel 161

There are/is 1 channel 40

Is there better way to do that?